# Искажение словаря в requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Есть класс, при создании которого заводится сессия `self.session = requests.Session()`

После чего происходит логин и другие действия. Всё работает нормально.

Далее я отправляю другой запрос `self.session.post(url, data=data)` и вот на этом месте всё ломается.

`data` до отправки =

```
{
    'fandomId': 1, 
    'languageId': 2, 
    'pages': [
        {
            'J_PAGE_TYPE': 1, 
            'J_TEXT': 'Yet another', 
            'J_SIZE': 0, 
            'align': 0, 
            'icon': 0
        }
    ]
}
```

А на сервер она попадает в другом виде:

```
{
    'fandomId': 1, 
    'languageId': 2, 
    'pages': [
        'J_PAGE_TYPE', 
        'J_TEXT', 
        'J_SIZE', 
        'align', 
        'icon'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло `json.dumps(data)`

Но мне всё же интересно, почему это произошло.